# CSS: Fix container at the top without specifying height

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to fix a container at the top without specifying a height?

I have a container which lays on the body so that there is a margin all around. The container is on `overflow: auto` so that it extends beyond the height of the screen (which is what I want, I do not want to specify a height).

What I am looking for is a way such that the container scrolls up but the margin stays visible (it scrolls up underneath the margin. Is there any way of doing that without fixing the height of the container?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/aybjbxvc/

It's they grey margin at the top that I would like to keep when it scrolls while everything else stays the way it is.

Comment: could you maybe make a code snippet or jsfiddle demonstrating it? I have kinda problems imagining what you want to do

Comment: Create fiddle, people are always ready o help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by putting `container` inside a **wrapper** div:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Declare these styles for `wrapper`, and it will take up all except the top 5% of the screen.

```
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  height: 95%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Remove the `overflow` and `padding` styles from `body` and `container`.  Change `body`'s margin to 0px.  These changes will remove extra scrollbars:

```
body {
  background: #e8e8e1;
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
  background: #fcfcf7;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #a1a19a;
}
```

### Fiddle

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

It wasn't 100% what I was looking for (to be fair I didn't specify enough) but that's the idea I needed. This is what I added (so that the shadow doesn't disappear etc.): [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6nderm2f/)